# Using JPA2.1 on Weblogic12 with Hibernate 5: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, weblogic12c

I'm getting really frustrated with the simple task of trying to use a JPA 2.1 PersistenceManager with Hibernate 5.

I package a simple web service built with the weblogic ant task jwsc (weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask)
but when deploying I get this `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
[wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():472] : Initiating deploy operation for app, import2, on targets:
 [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():474] :    myserver
 [wldeploy] Task 0 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application import2 on myserver.
 [wldeploy] dumping Exception stack
 [wldeploy] Task 0 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application import2 on myserver.
 [wldeploy] Target state: deploy failed on Server myserver
 [wldeploy] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
 [wldeploy]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 [wldeploy]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
 [wldeploy]     at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.getPersistenceProvider(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:441)
 [wldeploy]     at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:461)
 [wldeploy]     at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:454)
 [wldeploy]     at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.init(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:141)
```

The class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider is provided in hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.4.Final.jar.

My import2.war DOES include this jar in 
WEB-INF/lib along with other things:

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-java8-5.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

For the record, here is my persistence.xml, packaged in my WAR file in
    /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="AdminPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//########:1521/xe"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="#########"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="#########"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally, here is the place where I use the entityManager:

```
public class AdminDatabaseWebservice {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "AdminPersistenceUnit")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following.

```
public class AdminDatabaseWebservice {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "AdminPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    .....
```

Create the `entityManager` using `entityManagerFactory`.

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.createQuery("from Entity").getResultList();
```

Hope this helps.